# Do something after method returns

Tags: java, asynchronous, executable, deferred-execution

This is my situation in pseudocode:

```
function onRequest() {
    receiveConnectionRequest();

    response = function onConnect() {
        playersConnected++;
        if (playersConnected == 4) {
            sendAllPlayersTheirCards()
        }
        return OK;
    }();

    sendResponse(response);

}
```

When players 1-3 connect, they get added to the list of players and OK is returned to them, at which point they will set stuff up on their side. When player 4 connects, however, before the response to his request is sent, all players are sent their cards. Because player 4 has not received a response to his request yet, he hasn't initialised correctly yet and errors upon receiving his cards.

What I'd like to have is this:

```
function onRequest() {
    receiveConnectionRequest();

    response = function onConnect() {
        playersConnected++;
        if (playersConnected == 4) {
            plan(sendAllPlayersTheirCards())
        }
        return OK;
    }();

    sendResponse(response);

    executePlanned() // now cards are sent
}
```

Is there a general pattern for that? The onConnect function is in a different class and should not be aware of the implementation details of onRequest.

I'm specifically trying to implement this in Java, but generic solutions are welcome.

Comment: Looks like delegation. plan() is, here, setting up the delegation and executePlanned() is invoking the queued actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many good solutions to this, but I would suggest using a call back.

Don't think of it as doing something after the method returns, think of it as calling back to report a state or trigger an event.

Search for event pattern , or call backs in Java. Here is [one link I found](http://people.bu.edu/azs/teaching/cs108/2006fall/callback_pattern.pdf).

The [delegation pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) is very similar to.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not send the response first and then do the "if(playersConnected"  check after?

Comment: In my current setup, the response has to be returned by the function that checks whether all players are connected

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this closure syntax you have here.  Can you just have this instead?

```
function onRequest() {
    playersConnected++;

    sendResponse(OK);

    if (playersConnected == 4) {
        sendAllPlayersTheirCards()
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't because the code that handles the receiving of the request and the sending of the response is part of a generic package, and the code that does playersConnected++ is part of another, game-specific package.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a relevant tutorial:

[Using Callable to Return Results From Runnables](http://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/get_netbeans_6)

Answer (score 0):

I could do it like this:

```
function onRequest(request) {

 game.handleRequest(request, function(response) {
  sendResponse(response);
 }

}

class game
function handleRequest(request, sendResponse:Function) {
 players++;
 sendResponse(OK);
 if (players == 4) sendCards();
}
```